# Difference between Scala pattern matching using variable binding and guard

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

While pattern matching, what would be a scenario where variable binding would be necessary, where guarding would not suffice?

```
  "hello" match {
    case greeting @ ("yo" | "hello" | "hola") => println(s"greeting is $greeting")
    case _                                    => println("some other greeting")
  }

  "hello" match {
    case greeting if (greeting == "yo" || greeting == "hello" || greeting == "hola") => println(s"greeting is $greeting")
    case _ => println("some other greeting")
  }
```

Both of these approaches seem to be solving the same problem.

Comment: They may solve the same problem but I know which syntax is more idiomatic, elegant and readable...

Comment: Using a guard in such way is missing the whole point about pat/mat, rather directly use `if`, or just pat/mat, but wildcard pattern and guard is generally anti-pattern.

Comment: As we all know in scala `if` is an expression and in your second example you are almost doing something similar `val greeting = if (greeting == "yo" || greeting == "hello" || greeting == "hola")` and then printing the value of `greeting` which is not advisable to do atleast in `pattern matching` and morever you are creating the alias of result in first example which is much easier to read and recommended way to do pattern matching

Answer (score 0):

When matching on sealed traits, there's a huge difference

```
sealed trait Option[+A]
case class Some[A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]

val x: Option[String] = ???
```

With pattern matching it's nice and readable:

```
x match {
  case Some(string) => println("got " + string)
  case None => println("didn't get anything")
}
```

And also compiler will issue a warning if you miss a case:

```
x match {
  case Some(string) => println("got " + string)
} // gives you warning that match might fail on None
```

For guard version, you need to use casts, and there's no warnings for forgotten cases:

```
x match {
  case some if some.isInstanceOf[Some[_]] =>
    println("got " + some.asInstanceOf[Some[String]].get)
  case none if some == None =>
    println("didn't get anything")
}
```

---

Furthermore, guards get ugly quickly when want to check structure deeper than one level. Compare:

```
case Some(Some(string)) => println(string)
```

with

```
case s if s.isInstanceOf[Some[_]] && s.asInstanceOf[Some[_]].get.isInstanceOf[Some[_]] =>
  println(s.asInstanceOf[Some[_]].get.asInstanceOf[Some[String]].get)
```

Comment: I understand your points, but I am more interested in understanding when would a variable binding come in more handy. Is there a specific scenario or should I just prefer variable binding since its more readable and clean?